# Trying to isolate X in this formula

Tags: factoring

I have this formula:

Position in an array = $x + y$ * Self.width + layer * Self.width * Self.height

If I know the position how  can I find $x$ based on the position only with this formula?

How to find $x$?

Comment: Is the equation written correctly? Are all other variables known?

Comment: the equation is written correctly.. the variables Width, Layer and Height are known offcourse but they could be anything.

Comment: Y is not known through.

Comment: Can you provide some samples of these with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

$$x = \text{Position in an array}\, - \text{Self.width}\,\times\,(y + \,\text{layer}\,\times \,\text{Self.height})  \, $$

You'd have $x$ as a function of $y$.

You could also express $y$ as a function of $x$. In both cases, you'd have the equation of a line, but you would need to know one the value of one variable, either $x, y$, to solve for the other.